# Vim nmap :q to :Q not working

Tags: vim, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, keymapping

I have the following keymappings in my vimrc

```
nmap :Q<CR> :q<CR>
nmap :W<CR> :w<CR>
nmap :WQ<CR> :wq<CR>
```

However, they do nothing. Vim complains that Q isn't a valid command. Same for W and WQ. I restarted vim and everything. I'm trying to figure this out and I'm also hoping to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and the arrow keys to just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> for changing windows left and etc. How can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

For your second question:

```
nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h
nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k
nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l
```